# Protractor snippet returning unexpected value

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a block of code that I am trying to confirm the "name" value on, but it is returning an extremely unexpected value, and I hoping that someone can point me to where I went wrong.

The html that I am searching over is below:

```
<div class="col" ng-repeat="bank in firstBanks">
        <div style="font-size: 2em; ">
            <label class="bank_radio">
                <input type="radio" ng-model="bankConnection.bank" ng-value="bank" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="00D" value="[object Object]">
                <img ng-src="img/banks/bofa.png" src="img/banks/bofa.png">
            </label>
        </div>

</div>
```

I am attempting to grab the value found in name="00D" so I have the block of code below as an expect() to make sure that I am grabbing the right element before I move onto my next steps.

```
expect(element.all(by.repeater('bank in firstBanks')).get(0).element(by.css('[ng-value="bank"]')).getAttribute('name')).toEqual('00D');
```

For some reason it is constantly returning "011" with the error:

```
Message:
 Expected '011' to equal '00D'.
```

This is extremely confusing to me as I have nowhere on my page with the text "011" at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to Protractor and still getting a handle on the syntax.

EDIT:

Updated my snippet to be simplified per "alecxe" response. The error that is being returned now is the following "[ '011', '013', '015', '019', '01B' ] to equal '00D'". Does anyone have any idea where these values are being generated from? Because I do not have any of those in my page.

The repeater that I have setup does have 5 instances, and that matches the number that are being returned in that error message, but I feel like this are just being randomly set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the test by using [`by.model()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.model):

```
expect(element(by.model('bankConnection.bank')).getAttribute('name')).toEqual('00D');
```

or:

```
expect(element.all(by.model('bankConnection.bank')).get(0).getAttribute('name')).toEqual('00D');
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I changed what I had to simplify the test using the second line that you posted. I am now getting a return error message of: 

Expected [ '011', '013', '015', '019', '01B' ] to equal '00D'. I have no idea where or how these numbers are being generated, do you have a clue?

Comment: It does not seem to be able to correctly recognize the "name" attribute.

Comment: @parchambeau well, it looks like a list of hexadecimal numbers to me :) Are you really sure there is an element with `name="00D"`?

Comment: @parchambeau reverse it just to make a check: `expect(element(by.name('00D')).isPresent()).toBe(true);`.

Comment: Do you think that this might be something chrome developer tools is generating? When looking at my local file I actually do not have a value for "name" being set, but when looking at my page in chrome developer tools it is adding in a "name=00D", name="00F", name="00H", name="00L", name="00N" to each of my "bankConnection.bank" models.

Comment: @parchambeau yeah, it is just about that `name` attribute generation mechanism, I think. Inspect what is inside the angular template that is responsible for this part of the page.

Comment: This was returned when running the snippet you suggested. Message:
     Expected false to be true.
So it looks like that actually does not exist, but for some reason chrome is telling me that it does.